# extract specific data from a cell, MYSQL

Tags: mysql

ok, i have a table name ORDERS and i have a Column in the orders table named OrderedItems

within the ordered items the data looks like this example below

```
Flavor Name (10ml, 0mg nic)
Flavor Name (15ml, 12mg nic)
Flavor Name (15ml with Flavor Boost, 12mg nic)
Flavor Name (30ml, 24mg nic)
Flavor Name (30ml with Flavor Boost, 24mg nic)
```

i want to be able to extract the items below and put them in a View each its own column having the
Flavor Name 
10/15/30ml etc...
0/12/24mg etc...

i am not the best writing query's but if someone can point me in the right direction i might be able to get it done.

Any suggestion's? do i need to do this in excel or something like that?

Comment: i am using mysql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your format will be the same for ***all*** flavors...

```
SELECT Substring_index(flavor, ' (', 1)                        AS flavorName, 
       Substring(flavor, Locate('(', flavor) + 1, 
       ( Locate('ml', flavor) + 1 ) - Locate('(', flavor))     AS volumne, 
       Substring(flavor, Locate(', ', flavor) + 2, 
       Locate(' nic)', flavor) - ( Locate(', ', flavor) + 2 )) AS dose 
FROM   flavors
```

**Result**

```
|  FLAVORNAME | VOLUMNE | DOSE |
--------------------------------
| Flavor Name |    10ml |  0mg |
| Flavor Name |    15ml | 12mg |
| Flavor Name |    15ml | 12mg |
| Flavor Name |    30ml | 24mg |
| Flavor Name |    30ml | 24mg |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/526f6/5)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select orderId,
       sum(case when flavor_name like 'Chocolate%' then 1 else 0 end) as ChocolateCnt,
       sum(case when flavor_name like 'Vanilla%' then 1 else 0 end) as VanillaCnt,
       sum(case when flavor_name like 'Rocky Road%' then 1 else 0 end) as RockyRoadCnt
from orders o
group by orderId
```

Comment: i am not sure, with this statement you are basically saying each time in the view orderId Chocolate shows up count? and show up as a number? as the added #

Comment: the flavor name is actually something different in my example i just showed flavor name so i did not actually list the names of my products

Comment: i think that is on the right track though. anytime in the column OrderedItems that i see chocolate i want to extract then i need to do the same for (15ml, 12mg nic)

Comment: Chocolate (15ml, 24mg nic)

Comment: Thank youfor your help as well